# How to display the current time on a wp7 application?

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone-7

I have a `TextBlock` on my application. I want to update it every second to show the current time.

How should I do it? The first thing I though was to create an instance of a `System.Thread.Timer` and update the text...

```
clockTimer = new Timer(o =>
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        currentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
    });
}, null, 0, 1000);
```

But is it ok to call `Dispatcher` every second?

If I use a binding what will be its behavior? Is it better for performance than calling `Dispatcher`? (consider having several calls to `Dispatcher` every second and several bindings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a DispatcherTimer instead.

Something like this:

```
        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);

        dt.Tick += (s, e) => { currentTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); };

        dt.Start();
```

There shouldn't be harm in doing this, just don't hang around too long in your tick event.

Also, if you do it in binding, you're going to have to have a timer of some sort around it to update your bound property, so, though I always favor databinding over direct manipulation of the control, it shouldn't matter either way.

Answer (score 2):

> "is it ok to call Dispatcher every second?"

It's highly debatable.
If it's necessary for the functioning of the app then you must.
However, a mobile device is only any use while it has power in the battery. Every action your code makes ultimately ends up in using more power. If you can write (or design) the application to not need to have to do so much work then you'll ultimately avoid draining the battery faster.

One of the general priniciples behind all mobile development is to not do any work you don't have to, so you can preserve battery life.